# unix, merging several text file contents, horizontally (problems with paste)

Tags: bash, unix, paste

ok, let's I have a txt file like this...

```
X 1 :   D i s t a n c e   [ m m ] 
Y 1 :   I n t e n s i t y 
X 2 :   D i s t a n c e   [ m m ] 
Y 2 :   I n t e n s i t y 
I m a g e   ( 2 3 7 . 2 3   u )              

X 1                  Y 1         
0 . 0 0 0 0 0 0      4 0 . 0 0 0 0 0 0          
0 . 0 0 2 0 0 0      5 7 . 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

...etc
And several others similar to this...

```
X 1 :   D i s t a n c e   [ m m ] 
Y 1 :   I n t e n s i t y 
X 2 :   D i s t a n c e   [ m m ] 
Y 2 :   I n t e n s i t y 
I m a g e   ( 2 6 5 . 2 7   u )              

X 1                  Y 1          
0 . 0 0 0 0 0 0      3 6 . 0 0 0 0 0 0            
0 . 0 0 2 0 0 0      3 4 . 0 0 0 0 0 0            
0 . 0 0 4 0 0 0      4 0 . 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

When I use paste, to merge horizontally the content of these files...

```
#! /bin/bash
zeta=$(ls)    
paste $zeta >> file_1.txt
```

I get this (example if there were two files):

```
X 1 :   D i s t a n c e   [ m m ] 
X 1 :   D i s t a n c e   [ m m ] 

Y 1 :   I n t e n s i t y 
Y 1 :   I n t e n s i t y 

X 2 :   D i s t a n c e   [ m m ] 
X 2 :   D i s t a n c e   [ m m ] 

Y 2 :   I n t e n s i t y 
Y 2 :   I n t e n s i t y 

I m a g e   ( 2 3 7 . 2 3   u )              
I m a g e   ( 2 6 5 . 2 7   u )              

X 1                  Y 1         
X 1                  Y 1         

0 . 0 0 0 0 0 0      4 0 . 0 0 0 0 0 0       
0 . 0 0 0 0 0 0      3 6 . 0 0 0 0 0 0       

0 . 0 0 2 0 0 0      5 7 . 0 0 0 0 0 0       
0 . 0 0 2 0 0 0      3 4 . 0 0 0 0 0 0       

0 . 0 0 4 0 0 0      4 1 . 0 0 0 0 0 0       
0 . 0 0 4 0 0 0      4 0 . 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Why do I have this intermingle of lines?
How can I do to put exactly the content of a txt file just aside of the content of the other txt file? In this case have the columns 1 and 2 for my first file, and the columns 3 and 4 for my second file. And then massively for several files?

Thanks for any hint,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put several '\t' between context of the line and '\n' :

cat text1.txt | tr "\n" "\t\t\n" > text1.txt

After the processes, you can use your old method to paste them together. :)

Comment: No, it doesn't really solve the problem. I guess there is something in the paste function that I'm not able to understand,

Comment: may be there is '\n\n' rather than single '\n' in your text's line tail?

Comment: indeed, there is something weird at the end of the text, not sure what is it, I'll try to see if I erase that, it works better, thanks